# Through relativity could a person be dead and alive at the same time?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes

For the purposes of the question ignore the fact that radiation and several other things would kill humans long before this.

You and another person are jumping into a black hole and the other person is going first looking back at you falling shortly behind. Would the other person get to a point (probably at the event horizon)that they see you actually moving away from them at c, relatively, essentially escaping the black hole but then you (from your own own reference point)would experience death as you fall in?

Comment: Only if you're a cat.

Comment: There is no universal 'same time'.  Do you mean the same time according to the person in question?  If so, the answer is no.  Do you mean the same time according to someone else's clock?  If so, the answer is no.  Do you mean the 'same time' according to two different clocks?  In that case, reconsider what 'same time' means.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly... No. The first person falling in, while looking out, will see you following suit. This observed distance will be stretched, so one might think the person coming in second would briefly appear to gain distance from the POV of the first and 'move away' from the hole.

The stretching of distances likely will happen yes, but in either case the first person will see the second person moving towards the black hole the entire time. The reason for this is that in large part you don't notice anything odd when passing the event horizon - if you could perform such an experiment, you would notice the speed of light in both directions at the horizon is still $c$.

You might also think the second person 'falls in front of' the light entering the hole from the first person, and might 'see' this light in a reversed ordering. This will not happen either, again because *locally* you will never fall in faster than the light coming from a source that will fall in after you. The light must travel along space just like you do, but (in a way) it is the space that is actually falling into the hole carrying both you and light in with it; what makes the horizon special is at that point, space is "falling in" faster than $c$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what your setup is, precisely. I will comment that no observer will ever observe a massive object to be moving at or faster than $c$, nor would this lead you out of the black hole (after all, photons get trapped).

I will say that in relativity, the order in which events happen can be observer dependent. It is therefore possible that to some observers, your death-event has not yet occurred, while to other observers (...like, sure, you), it has.